# How to solve $f(x)\frac{dy}{dx}=yf'(x)-y^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $f(x)$ be a given differentiable function, solve the differential equation in $y$
$f(x)\frac{dy}{dx}=yf'(x)-y^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write as:
$$
\frac{y f'(x)-y' f(x)}{y^2} = 1
$$
Does this remind you of a differentiation rule?

Comment: @Did Thanks for the edit. I was about to make it myself.

Comment: I am sure you would have. Nice hint.